# How to reference parent resource in module in azure bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I am trying to create a service bus and topic (many topics and their subscriptions) with the azure bicep.

1. I have main bicep like below

   ```
   param topics array;

   resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2018-01-01-preview' = {
   name: serviceBusNamespaceName
   location: location
    sku: {
      name: skuName
    }
   }

   module topicSubscription './sb_topic.bicep' = [for topic in topics: {
   name: 'topicSubscription${topic}'
   params: {
   topic: topic
     }
   }]
   ```

module file looks like

```
resource sbTopics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: topic.name
  parent: ??
  properties: topic.properties

  resource symbolicname 'subscriptions@2022-01-01-preview' =  [for subscription in topic.subscriptions: {
    name: 'string'
    properties: {}
  }]
}
```

How can pass the parent serviceBusNamespace resource as parent to the child resource inside the module?

Kindly suggest..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bicep module reference as a parent in another resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486988/bicep-module-reference-as-a-parent-in-another-resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the module reference the namespace with an 'existing' declaration.  Something like this

```
param namespaceName string

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
  name: namespaceName
}

resource sbTopics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: topic.name
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  properties: topic.properties

  resource symbolicname 'subscriptions@2022-01-01-preview' =  [for subscription in topic.subscriptions: {
    name: 'string'
    properties: {}
  }]
}
```